# Combining two POST requests using httr

Tags: r, httr, exact-online

I need to create a POST request, that needs another POST request.

So there are two different POST requests, that can not be executed individually. How will I be able to combine those two requests?

For reference, I need to POST to [Exact Online](https://www.exact.com/). They have a [REST API documentation](https://start.exactonline.nl/docs/HlpRestAPIResources.aspx?SourceAction=10) that should make things easier. In my example, I want to create a new purchase order, found [here](https://start.exactonline.nl/docs/HlpRestAPIResourcesDetails.aspx?name=PurchaseOrderPurchaseOrders). There are two mandatory properties: "Supplier" and "PurchaseOrderLines". The supplier is easy to state but the purchase order lines are created with [a second POST request](https://start.exactonline.nl/docs/HlpRestAPIResourcesDetails.aspx?name=PurchaseOrderPurchaseOrderLines).

Individually, the POST request for PurchaseOrderLines would for example be like this:

```
POST(url = paste("https://start.exactonline.nl/api/v1/", division, "/purchaseorder/PurchaseOrderLines", sep = ""),
     add_headers(Key = "authorization", Authorization = paste("Bearer", accessToken, sep = " ")),
     body = list(Item = "ItemCode", PurchaseOrderId = "999999", QuantityInPurchaseUnits = "1.0"),
     encode = "json")
```

For the actual PurchaseOrder request, so far I have this:

```
POST(url = paste("https://start.exactonline.nl/api/v1/", division, "/purchaseorder/PurchaseOrders", sep = ""),
     add_headers(Key = "authorization", Authorization = paste("Bearer", accessToken, sep = " ")),
     body = list(Supplier = "SupplierName", PurchaseOrderID = "999999"), encode = "json")
```

As stated in the documentation: "Purchase order lines may not be posted individually. They should be part of the PurchaseOrder Post."

So the question is: how do I make the purchase order lines a part of the PurchaseOrder Post.

Answer (score 0):

In general, on Exact Online you can combine multiple request using OData batching. This only works when the traffic goes to one end point (URL).

However, your question is more functional in nature. Exact requires that each transaction has at least one line (I know it's stupid, but live with it). This holds for both user interface as well as APIs which reflect this business rule.

In your PurchaseOrder create event, you need to send the lines along as part of the message.

Please check https://start.exactonline.nl/docs/HlpRestAPIResourcesDetails.aspx?name=PurchaseOrderPurchaseOrders and search for "Collection" in the text.

There the lines (at least 1) need to be inserted.

When you don't the exact syntax, please use an `insert into exactonlinerest..purchaseorders ... identified by ...` in Invantive SQL and then run it. In `select * from sessionios@datadictionary` you will find the actual call. When you enable native tracing, you can see the payload sent to Exact Online in the debug trace view.

As a side note, for uploading data I generally prefer using the XML API. It is faster and smarter.

## Running Sample

Start dbgview.
Enable trace logging using INVANTIVE_TRACE_ACTIVE = true environment variable.
Start invantive control or other sql product.
Run this code to create a duplicate of every sales order in a new one:

```
set trace-native-calls true

begin transaction

insert into exactonlinerest..salesorders
( description
, orderedby
, deliverto
, deliveryaddress
, invoiceto
)
select 'EDI order '
       || ' van '
       || to_char(sysdate, 'DD-MM-YYYY')
       description
,      sor.orderedby
       label 'Ordered by account ID'
,      sor.deliverto
       label 'Deliver to account ID'
,      sor.deliveryaddress
       label 'Deliver to address ID'
,      sor.invoiceto
       label 'Invoice to account ID'
from   ( select orderid, orderedby, invoiceto, deliverto, deliveryaddress  from exactonlinerest..salesorders ) sor
identified
by     sor.orderid

insert into exactonlinerest..salesorderlines
( description
, item
, quantity
, unitcode
)
select sle.description
,      sle.item
,      sle.quantity
,      sle.unitcode
from   exactonlinerest..salesorderlines sle
attach
to     sle.orderid

commit
```

Result:
[image: Sales order]

Native trace:

```
[49784] 15:02:21.82979-45: POST 962 bytes of data to URL '/api/v1/868047/salesorder/SalesOrders'. Disk cache: False/False, memory cache False/False. 
[49784] 15:02:21.82979-45: Native request body on POST to 'https://start.exactonline.nl/api/v1/868047/salesorder/SalesOrders': 
[49784] 15:02:21.82979-45: {"DeliverTo":"3ee8cdbc-e71c-4e8b-b4ee-922e84b05abf","DeliveryAddress":"fa6f3eb2-ba09-4c9f-aeb0-c967bdd8004f","Description":"EDI order  van 08-12-2018","InvoiceTo":"3ee8cdbc-e71c-4e8b-b4ee-922e84b05abf","OrderedBy":"3ee8cdbc-e71c-4e8b-b4ee-922e84b05abf","SalesOrderLines":[{"Description":"Basebal handschoen links","Item":"ee4d1e32-4296-4460-908c-d109b9c2ac77","Quantity":25.0,"UnitCode":"stuk"},{"Description":"Basebal handschoen rechts","Item":"8ee41235-7688-4201-a142-ba56feb393c6","Quantity":10.0,"UnitCode":"stuk"},{"Description":"Basebal","Item":"1f61a71a-4503-407f-8b32-0f63f51a1dae","Quantity":50.0,"UnitCode":"stuk"},{"Description":"Energydrink","Item":"2d37742d-1101-49c6-8c09-59055a808415","Quantity":150.0,"UnitCode":"stuk"},{"Description":"Basebal knuppel","Item":"858cbee5-f597-4333-8679-4083c896cf9f","Quantity":30.0,"UnitCode":"stuk"},{"Description":"Energy reep","Item":"1cb1c87c-2dc4-4be9-8be6-54347403680d","Quantity":100.0,"UnitCode":"stuk"}]} 
[49784] 15:02:21.89579-3: Response status 'OK', length 226.
```

and many more messages.

Comment: So how do I "send the lines along as part of the message"? Do you mean something like this: `body = list(Supplier = "SupplierName", PurchaseOrderID = "999999", 
                 PurchaseOrderLines = c(Item = "ItemCode", PurchaseOrderId = "999999", 
                                        QuantityInPurchaseUnits = "1.0"))`?

Comment: The API is rest so Json. Best add Json set of data accordingly to your language chosen or try scenario described to get some working payload and then mimic that Json using your language.

Comment: I use `encode = "json"` in the POST request so there is no need to add the lines as Json.

Comment: Added sample. encode = json is something of R which I may gamble what it does, but do not know.